# wpf Horizontal gridline in gridview

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I just want to show horizontal gridline between rows in listview. Is it possible?
All the post i have seen talks about vertical and horizontal grid lines using border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. You would just have to change the `ListView`'s [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx), so that it contains a line below the actual item.

You can easily do that by adjusting the default style which you can find [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#themes) (click the "Download" link in the "Themes" section).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following link, it might help.
[WPF ListView Vertical Lines+Horizontal Lines as Bonus](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/12/16/wpf-listview-vertical-lines-horizontal-as-bonus.aspx)